# Möbius transform of floor function

Tags: number-theory

Let $a$ be a positive integer. What is the result $g_a(n)$ of möbius transform of floor function

$$g_a(n) = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \bigg\lfloor \frac{n}{a d} \bigg\rfloor ?$$

We have

$$g_a(n) =\frac{1}{a} \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) \left(\frac{n}{d} - \text{mod}\left(\frac{n}{d}, a \right) \right) $$
$$ = \frac{1}{a} \phi(n) - \frac{1}{a}\sum_{d | n} \mu(d)\text{mod}\left(\frac{n}{d}, a \right)$$

where $\mu$ is the Möbius function and $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function.

Comment: It is $\sum_{am \le n} 1_{gcd(m,n) = 1}$. There is no magic formula. You can express $\lfloor n/a \rfloor$ and hence $g_a(n)$ as a linear combination of multiplicatives functions coming from $\frac{L(s,\chi)}{\zeta(s)}$ and $\frac{L(s-1,\chi)}{\zeta(s)}$ where $\chi$ are the Dirichlet characters modulo $a$.